# Duplicate inbox, junk, outbox etc - how do I remove these without causing problems?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I had to reinstall Outlook 2010 when I upgraded to i5 - I have 7 email addresses, put these back into Outlook ok - each email address has it's own inbox, outbox, junk etc. but I also have another set of folders, not associated with any email address that I don't want.

Before I upgraded, my Outlook, although having 7 email addresses showed only one each of each folder - I would like this again, but if I can't I'll settle for "just" the 7 sets of everything - it's a pain but better than creating a new rule - did this for all incoming to go to one folder but by the time I received, read, moved or deleted it took just as long as expanding each email address and reading them - so now I have whatever email I receive going to their respective "homes" but I would like to get the duplicate folders out of Outlook - suggestions welcomed, thank you